# C Void pointer as an argument

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, memory-address

I'm trying to pass in something by address. In this case a char array but it could be anything.

```
void rickyHashTableAdd(rickyHashTable *table, char *key, void *value)
{
    rickyHashTableEntry entry;
    entry.key = strdup(key);    
    entry.value = value;
    table->entries[0] = entry;
}

int rickyHashTableGet(rickyHashTable *table, char *key, void *value)
{
    value = table->entries[0].value;
}

int main (void) 
{       
    void *val;
    val = "what up";
    rickyHashTableAdd(&symbolTable, "ok", val);
    void *val2;
    rickyHashTableGet(&symbolTable, "ok", val2);
    printf("result: %s\n", val2);
```

}

When I check the value of 'value' inside the rickyHashTableGet function it is correct, but when I check in in main after the function has been called it's bad. It seems to not be setting to the right memory address. Why is this?

Comment: You have to set `val2` to some kind of value before you pass it to `rickyHashTableGet`! Also, `rickyHashTableGet` sets `value` to something and then throws it away. Did you want to return it? Or did you want to pass a pointer to it instead of passing it by value?

Answer (score 2):

```
int rickyHashTableGet(rickyHashTable *table, char *key, void *value)
{
    value = table->entries[0].value;
}
```

This ignores the `value` that was passed. Sets `value` to something and then throws it away. This can't be right.

```
void *val2;
rickyHashTableGet(&symbolTable, "ok", val2);
```

This doesn't set `val2` to anything, and thus passes a nonsense value to `rickyHashTableGet`. That can't be right.

You want:

```
int rickyHashTableGet(rickyHashTable *table, char *key, void **value)
{
    *value = table->entries[0].value;
}
```

That takes a pointer to a `void *` and makes it point to something.

And:

```
void *val2;
rickyHashTableGet(&symbolTable, "ok", &val2);
```

That passes the *address* of `val2` to `rickyHashTableGet`, so it can set its value.

Answer (score 0):

In your get routine, it should be void **get as the parameter and *value = table->entries[0].value;   The call would then use &val2.